# How to give group name for dynamic columns in a gridview while exporting to pdf in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itext, pdf-generation, export-to-pdf

```
                               Course
 ------------------------------------------                         
     Id   Name   Department   BBA MBA BBM
 ------------------------------------------       
      1   John     commerce   Yes  
      2   David    commerce       Yes
```

The above is a sample grid with ID,Name,Department as static fields and BBA,MBA,BBM as dynamic fields in a gridview with a group name course.I need to export this gridview to pdf with all columns including the group name.How to export to pdf in asp.net with group name header?

Comment: Grid? U mean grid view?

Comment: yes grid view @ Pratik Ghag

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the tutorial for iText7, it will show you exactly how to use iText to create a table.
http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/clone-101-very-simple-table